# sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) using findElement(By.className()) through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait, linktext

When I execute the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("qview-product-name")).click();
```

I get the following error

```
Session ID: d5df6f837164b1738991e8dc09027fe0
*** Element info: {Using=class name, value=qview-product-name}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByClassName(RemoteWebDriver.java:412)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:389)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at Logins.bcLogin(Logins.java:140)
    at Exception.main(Exception.java:54)
```

The webpage I am working on definately contains the following HTML code and I have tried waiting an appropriate amount of time to execute.

```
<dd class="qview-product-name">
    <span class="note">1 x </span>
                    <a href="Link_here"_blank">Title</a>
            </dd>
```

I thought I was getting pretty good at locating elements using the various methods, but this has me stumped. Any ideas on how I should go about troubleshooting? Thanks!

Comment: Try this: `driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Title")).click();`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you need to take care of:

- `By.className("qview-product-name")` refers to the parent `<dd>` tag and perhaps is not the desired element you want to click. Rather your usecase must be to click on the `<a href="Link_here"_blank">Title</a>` element.
- As per best practices, while invoking `click()` you need to induce you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- `linkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Title"))).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("dd.qview-product-name a[href='Link_here']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//dd[@class='qview-product-name']//a[@href='Link_here' and text()='Title']"))).click();
  ```

---

### Additional Considerations

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v77.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to the current *Chrome Version 77.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v77.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.