# java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) when using improper code with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

For the sake of fast prototyping I have used the below Selenium Webdriver java code (in fact, it doesn't meet the best practices, but it should work anyway, despite of being non-optimal).

```
if (!driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-popup-element__close']")).isEmpty()) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-popup-element__close']")).click();
}
```

I.e. it has the same value in the `findElement()`. When it is put into the while loop, it throws at some loop the exceptions.

```
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 77.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20200602222727, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.26.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 12120, moz:profile: C:\Users\eljah32\AppData\Lo..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 77ad55a3-7cc3-4126-a91d-f0b63c438520
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at SeleniumConfirmRNN.main(SeleniumConfirmRNN.java:122)
```

Selenium libraries versions:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

So, what to do with this problem and is it a bug? That happens for `FirefoxDriver`.

Comment: What is your Java / JDK version?

Comment: @HelpingHands 12.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 77.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20200602222727, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.26.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 12120, moz:profile: C:\Users\eljah32\AppData\Lo..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 77ad55a3-7cc3-4126-a91d-f0b63c438520
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* was unable to `click()` on the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) within the *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session.

---

There are a couple of things you need to consider as follows:

- First of all, you don't invoke `click()` on a `<div>` element unless the element contains the attribute **`contenteditable="true"`**.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to modify the innerHTML of a contenteditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914416/how-to-modify-the-innerhtml-of-a-contenteditable-element/52917565#52917565)

- Presumably, there should be a child `<input>` or `<span>` element which is your desired element within the `<div>` you are referring. So you need to move one step deeper to locate the [**interactable**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690971/selenium-webdriver-throws-exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-element/44691041#44691041) element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  try {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-popup-element__close']//input"))).click();
    System.out.println("Element was clicked");
  }
  catch(TimeoutException e) {
    System.out.println("Element wasn't clicked");
  }
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) using findElement(By.className()) through Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195202/sun-reflect-nativeconstructoraccessorimpl-newinstance0native-method-using-find/58196479#58196479)

Comment: Thank you! I believe that my code here is far from the best practices. So I was just surprised that the exception thrown is a reflection exception, not a Selenium's one.